# Trying to crack XOR key for project (python2.7)

Tags: python, xor

Hi im trying to to encrypt a code then try and find the key for the code but not getting the best results with dont know what i can do here

```
from itertools import izip, cycle
import itertools
import binascii
a = 0
message = "Hello friend"
length = len(message)
key = "s"
c = 0
def xor_crypt_string(data, key):
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x,y) in izip(data, cycle(key)))

encrypt = xor_crypt_string(message, key)

while (c <= length):
    res = itertools.permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', c) # 3 is the length of your result.
    c = c + 1
    for i in res: 
        keys = ''.join(i)
        decrypt = xor_crypt_string(encrypt, keys)
        for d in decrypt:
            if (ord(d) > 47 and ord(d) < 58) or (ord(d) == 32) or (ord(d) > 64 and ord(d) < 91) or (ord(d) > 96 and ord(d) <123):
                print decrypt
            else: 
                a = 0
```

Comment: `ord(d) > 47 and ord(d) < 58` is better spelt `47 < ord(d) < 58`

Comment: Rather than putting in your title ,there is a tag for python2.x. You can use that!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want a call to `all` rather than a regular `for` loop when you're checking if your decryption is valid. That will test all the characters and only print the decryption if they're all valid:

```
if all(x == 32 or 47 < x < 58 or 64 < x < 91 or 96 < x < 123
       for x in (ord(c) for c in decrypt)):
   print decrypt
```

You can make your test even clearer than I have above by using a string or set membership test, rather than explicitly checking ordinal ranges (e.g. `if all(c in string.printable for c in decrypt)` is only a little more broad than your test).